# How can I load multiple gpx files into PostGIS?

Tags: python, sql, gis, postgis, gpx

I have a bunch of gpx files that come from [GPSLogger for Android](https://github.com/mendhak/gpslogger) app.

Files look like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<gpx  version="1.0" creator="GPSLogger - http://gpslogger.mendhak.com/"  
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  
  xmlns="http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/0" 
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/0 
    http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/0/gpx.xsd" >
  <time>2011-08-26T06:25:20Z</time>
  <bounds></bounds>
  <trk>
    <trkseg>
      <trkpt  lat="46.94681501102746"  lon="7.398453755309032" >
        <ele>634.0</ele>
        <speed>0.0</speed>
        <src>gps</src>
        <sat>6</sat>
        <time>2011-08-26T06:25:20Z</time>
      </trkpt>
      <trkpt  lat="46.94758878281887"  lon="7.398622951942811" >
        <ele>748.0</ele>
        <speed>0.0</speed>
        <src>gps</src>
        <sat>5</sat>
        <time>2011-08-26T06:30:56Z</time>
      </trkpt>

...   ...   ...

    </trkseg>
  </trk>
</gpx>
```

Is it possible to traverse a directory containing these files and load them into one PostGIS table using either SQL or Python?

I've stubled upon [this](http://postneo.com/2007/01/20/from-gpx-to-postgis) blog post mentioning that:

> I’m not aware of anything that can convert straight from GPX to
>   PostGIS

[This post](http://www.postgresonline.com/journal/archives/116-Loading-and-Processing-GPX-XML-files-using-PostgreSQL.html) gives an example of working with SQL to do that but I can't get my head around the code :/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[ogr2ogr](http://www.gdal.org/ogr2ogr.html) (part of GDAL) is a simple and straightforward Unix shell tool to load a GPX file into PostGIS.

```
ogr2ogr -append -f PostgreSQL PG:dbname=walks walk.gpx
```

ogr2ogr creates its own database tables in PostGIS with its own schema. The table `tracks` has one row per GPS track; `tracks.wkb_geometry` contains the GPS track itself as a MultiLineString. The table `track_points` contains individual location fixes (with timestamps).

Here is what the database `walks` looks like before the import:

```
walks=# \d
               List of relations
 Schema |       Name        | Type  |  Owner   
--------+-------------------+-------+----------
 public | geography_columns | view  | postgres
 public | geometry_columns  | view  | postgres
 public | raster_columns    | view  | postgres
 public | raster_overviews  | view  | postgres
 public | spatial_ref_sys   | table | postgres
(5 rows)
```

... and after the import:

```
walks=# \d
                    List of relations
 Schema |           Name           |   Type   |  Owner   
--------+--------------------------+----------+----------
 public | geography_columns        | view     | postgres
 public | geometry_columns         | view     | postgres
 public | raster_columns           | view     | postgres
 public | raster_overviews         | view     | postgres
 public | route_points             | table    | postgres
 public | route_points_ogc_fid_seq | sequence | postgres
 public | routes                   | table    | postgres
 public | routes_ogc_fid_seq       | sequence | postgres
 public | spatial_ref_sys          | table    | postgres
 public | track_points             | table    | postgres
 public | track_points_ogc_fid_seq | sequence | postgres
 public | tracks                   | table    | postgres
 public | tracks_ogc_fid_seq       | sequence | postgres
 public | waypoints                | table    | postgres
 public | waypoints_ogc_fid_seq    | sequence | postgres
(15 rows)
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are using linux, you may try this:

1. Use a program to convert GPX to SHP: *gpx2shp*

   ```
   sudo apt-get install gpx2shp
   ...
   gpx2shp -o output_file.shp infile.gpx
   ```
2. then load that file into a postgis enabled database with *shp2pgsql*

   ```
   sudo apt-get install postgis
   ...
   shp2pgsql output_file.shp gis_table
   ```

you may of course use pipe and make all in one command line

For more info see the manpages.

EDIT
If you still want a python script, you may find help here
http://pypi.python.org/pypi/gpxtools

Comment: thanks for pointers. would that solution give me separate shp file for each gpx input? or is it possible to combine all gpx files into one shp?

Comment: @radek You could import gpx files to R, merge them and export them using to a shape file using rgdal. Of course, once you have the gps files in R, you could also use SQL to import the data into a PostGIS DB.

Comment: @Roman: thanks. i did some work with R + SQL + Postgres so should be able to sort this part. is there any particular method/package you could recommend to work with gpx files tho?

Comment: There's a function to read gpx (`readGPS` I think) files in maptools (uses gpsbabel). I also wrote a gpx scraper function that uses only the XML package. Drop me a line if you'd be interested in giving it a try (looking for beta testers anyway :) ).

Comment: @Roman: i'm trying to find my way through this problem in R as well. afaik `readGPS()` is interface to [GPSBabel](http://www.gpsbabel.org/) software. i tried using `system()` call with manual definition of parameters, but had no success so far. would greatly appreciate if you could share your work :]

Comment: If you're on Windows, you can add the gpsbabel directory (where the exe is located) into the environmental path (PATH) and you'll have access to it directly through the readGPS function (that calls `system`).